# CSS transition not working when a class is removed

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to open AND close my nav menu smoothly.

When the toggle button is clicked, the  `.responsive`
class is added/removed from  `.topnav`
and  `.links`
classes.

My code is working for the `.topnav` class, by using the height transition. This has a smooth transition when the `.responsive` class is added AND removed.

For the `.links` class, I have attempted to use `transform: translateY(-250px);` and `top: -250px;`
Both of these transitions work when the `.responsive` class is added.

However there is no animation when the `.responsive` class is removed.

What can I do to solve this? Thank you

EDIT: I put this in a JS Fiddle, and the barebones code is actually working.
I will remove things from my actual code until i find the problem, and will post solution here.

```js
var toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-btn');
var topNav = document.querySelector('.topnav');
var links = document.querySelector('.links');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  topNav.classList.toggle('responsive');
  links.classList.toggle('responsive');
});
```

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  transition: height 300ms linear;
}

.topnav.responsive { 
  position: relative;
  height: 320px;
}

.links {
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
  top: -300px;
}

.links.responsive {
  transition: all 300ms linear;
  top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <span class="toggle-btn">Toggle</span>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#1">1</a>
    <a href="#2">2</a>
    <a href="#3">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the HTML structure.

```
<div class="topnav">
   <span class="toggle-btn">Toggle</span>
</div>  

<div class="links">
   <a href="#1">1</a>
   <a href="#2">2</a>
   <a href="#3">3</a>
</div>
```

I had to separate the two classes instead of having one nested inside the other.